# How to prove clock equivalence is a time-abstracted bisimulation

Tags: automata-theory, model-checking, formal-methods, program-verification, temporal-logic

An important step of developing the theory of timed automata is to reduce the question of reachability in the timed automata, which has infinitely-many states, to the question of reachability in an associated finite-state automaton constructed by grouping together clock valuations into so-called **clock regions**. To recall, we have a finite set $C$ whose elements we call **clocks**, and a **clock valuation** is then a function $\nu : C \to [0, \infty)$ which assigns every clock the elapsed amount of time that has progressed.

Note: We will write $\{r\}$ for the fractional part of a real number, so that $\{r\} = r - \lfloor r \rfloor$.

We start by choosing a constant $M$ which is larger than any constant appearing on a guard or invariant condition in the timed automaton we are studying, then we introduce an equivalence relation by stating $\nu_1 \approx \nu_2$ if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $\nu_1(x) > M$ if and only if $\nu_2(x) > M$ for all $x \in C$
2. If $\nu_1(x) \le M$ then $\lfloor \nu_1(x) \rfloor = \lfloor \nu_2(x) \rfloor$
3. If $\nu_1(x) \le M$ then $\{\nu_1(x)\} = 0$ iff $\{\nu_2(x)\} = 0$.
4. If $\nu_1(x) \le M$ and $\nu_1(y) \le M$ then $\{\nu_1(x)\} \le \{\nu_1(y)\}$ if and only if $\{\nu_2(x)\} \le \{\nu_2(y)\}$.

The idea is then to consider the equivalence classes $[\nu]$ of clock valuations under this equivalence relation, which are called **regions**.

In order for the theory to work, we need to show that clock equivalence induces a time-abstracted bisimulation on the timed automaton. The difficult step in establishing this, is to show the following Lemma.

Aside: Given a clock valuation $\nu$ alongside a number $c \in [0, \infty)$ define the clock valuation $\nu + c$ by setting $(\nu + c)(x) = \nu(x) + c$ for every $x \in C$.

**Lemma:** If $\nu_1 \approx \nu_2$ then for every $c_1 \in [0,\infty)$ there exists $c_2 \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\nu_1 + c_1 \approx \nu_2 + c_2$.

My question is how to prove this lemma.

All chains of citations in the literature seem to take me back to page 17 of the paper "Model-Checking in Dense Real-Time" by Rajeev Alur and Costas Courcoubetis. However, I do not find the proof provided there to be clear at all.

It is easy to prove

**Lemma:** If $\nu_1 \approx \nu_2$ then for every $c \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that $\nu_1 + c \approx \nu_2 + c$.

which allows us to reduce to the slightly more constrained problem

**Lemma:** If $\nu_1 \approx \nu_2$ then for every $c_1 \in (0, 1)$ there exists $c_2 \in [0, \infty)$ such that $\nu_1 + c_1 \approx \nu_2 + c_2$.

One can also show that whatever the choice of $c_2$, it has to be in $[0, 1)$ in order to be correct.

I'm personally being led to the conjecture that the solution is to set
$$ \tau(\nu) := \sup \{ \epsilon \ge 0 \mid \nu + \epsilon \approx \nu \} $$
and choose $c_2 = c_1 - \tau(\nu_1) + \tau(\nu_2)$.

Edit: Shaull points out that this conjecture is false.

Comment: I don't think your approach with $\tau(v)$ can work. Take two clocks $x,y$, and set $v_1(x)=0.3, v_1(y)=0.9$ and $v_2(x)=0.4, v_2(y)=0.5$, then $\tau(v_1)=0.1$ and $\tau(v_2)=0.5$. Now take $c_1=0.6$, then $v_1+c_1=(0.9,1.5)$ ("lower triangle"). But $c_2=0.6-0.1+0.5=1$, so you'll get $v_2+c_2=(1.4,1.5)$ ("upper triangle").
I think the reason you didn't find a proof is because it's easier to see it visually than write the technical details. I'll see if I can find a clean way to write it. If so, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, \tau(\nu) definitely doesn't work. At least with 1, 2, or 3 clocks it's visually clear. But I feel like it's important to make sure we really have a formal proof, otherwise its a bit strange to build a theory for verifying timed programs in which we don't have a formal verification of the theory itself!